# How to sendkeys "time" in time type element?

Tags: selenium

I need to pass data in time format in "time" type element in "10:00 AM" format.
I am using following code:

```
public static void setShift()
{
     txttime.sendkeys("1030AM");
}
```

this is not working. what is a correct way to enter such data?

Comment: is there any error message shows for this code?

Comment: I run this script and its working on my PC:-`WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`
        `driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/test/");` `WebElement dateBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form//input[@name='bdaytime']"));` `dateBox.sendKeys("09252013");` `dateBox.sendKeys("0245PM");`

Answer (score 1):

**Use Following Code :**

> It will work it for textbox/text area control

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
Date date = new Date();
txttime.sendkeys(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the HTML input type `datetime-local` handling it from selenium is not ideal. It is not the most used date time picker, and it is not supported in firefox or safari.

For chrome, the date time format shows the format set in the browser's machine.

If you haven't changed anything, I'm guessing you are getting the format shown in the *guru99* tutorial.

If that is the case, then you have missed that they also have provided the solution there. 
After entering the date part you need to press tab to input the time part. Which is missing from your given code.

**Try this:**

**First,** input the date

```
WebElement dateBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form//input[@name='bdaytime']"));
dateBox.sendKeys("09252013");
```

**Second,** press tab

```
dateBox.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```

**Last,** input the time

```
dateBox.sendKeys("0245PM");
```

**Note:**
If your machine has different DateTime formatting then this might not work. You have to check which part of the date time `senKeys` can actually input then split up that part and use `Keys.TAB` to press tab. Then input the next part until completion.